# List comparison in python

Tags: python, list

When i have two lists like below

```
h = [{"a":1,"b":2}]
p = [{"a":1,"b":2}]

a = [d for d in h if d in p]

print(a)

# [{"a":1,"b":2}]
```

But when **my first list changed like below**,

```
h = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5}]
p = [{"a":1,"b":2}]

a = [d for d in h if {d["a"], d["b"]} in p]  # It is not working 

print(a)
# [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5}]  - Expected o/p
```

but how can I achieve above. My question is, in my first list I may have more elements but I want to compare only the first two elements from List1 to List2 and find the matched items.

How can I do this ?

Comment: The *lists* all have exaclty *one* element each: a dictionary. And for a dictionary there is no 'first' element.

Comment: This does not work, because `{d["a"], d["b"]}` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (containing the numbers 1 and 2), which is not contained in the list `p`. Apart from that, I cannot give you a better answer, because it is not entirely clear to me what your criterion is for items of `h` to be added to `a`. Are you sure that you need to wrap a single dictionary in a list?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Print elements (in your example, dictionaries) that are both in the list `ħ` and `p`?

Comment: It is obviously not a clear question. Your lists have only one element, which is a dictionary. Also dictionaries do not have order in elements unless you use an `OrderedDict`. Do you want to compare each dictionary on both lists according to some specific keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [d for d in h if {"a":d.get("a"), "b":d.get("b")} in p]  #
```

If you only have a single dict in b then use `==`, considering you only use keys `a` and `b` you must either have repeated dicts or only one.

```
a = [d for d in h if {"a":d.get("a"), "b":d.get("b")} == {"a":1,"b":2}]
```

Using `d.get("a")` will avoid a keyerror if any of the dicts in h don't have an a or b key.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
a = [d for d in h if {"a": d["a"], "b": d["b"]}  in p]
```